# Remove Duplicate Values from Table and leave the ID with the most current date

Tags: sql

Not a SQL guru, but I need a SQL statement that will return a table of unique values with the most current date, so remove all the duplicate values based on ID and keep the ID with the most current date.

My current SQL statement is this:

```
Select Bill_To_Merchant_ID, Agreement_Termination_Notification_Date
From STG.Fact_Agreement
```

Current result:

```
Bill_To_Merchant_ID     Agreement_Termination_Notification_Date
----------------------------------------------------------------
   1                    01/09/2020
   1                    03/09/2020
   2                    05/09/2020
   2                    07/09/2020
   3                    06/09/2020
   3                    16/09/2020
```

Expected result:

```
Bill_To_Merchant_ID     Agreement_Termination_Notification_Date
----------------------------------------------------------------
   1                    03/09/2020
   2                    07/09/2020
   3                    16/09/2020
```

If there are no duplicates, that record remains in the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to actually *delete* the not most recent records, then use:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.Bill_To_Merchant_ID = t2.Bill_To_Merchant_ID AND
                    t2.Agreement_Termination_Notification_Date > t1.Agreement_Termination_Notification_Date);
```

If you instead can tolerate just *viewing* your data as in the expected output, then aggregation should work:

```
SELECT
    Bill_To_Merchant_ID,
    MAX(Agreement_Termination_Notification_Date) AS Agreement_Termination_Notification_Date 
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Bill_To_Merchant_ID;
```

Comment: Hi I want to keep most recent record and delete values with older date as shown in the example above.

Comment: @Route217 Then use my first query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `group by`:

```
select Bill_To_Merchant_ID, max(Agreement_Termination_Notification_Date)
from STG.Fact_Agreement
group by Bill_To_Merchant_ID;
```